# JTextArea added to BorderLayout is not visible

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

I have four components and I want to add them to the frame which has BorderLayout set. MenuBar goes to the North, JScrollPane goes to the Center, JTextField goes to the South and JTextArea goes to the East. The problem is that the last component is not visible.

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(scrollChatPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(myMessage, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add(users, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

The code above works as follows:

[image]

But when I replace my components with simple buttons, everything works fine:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

add(new Button("North"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(new Button("Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(new Button("South"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add(new Button("West"), BorderLayout.WEST);
add(new Button("East"), BorderLayout.EAST);
```

The code above works as follows:

[image]

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JTextArea` has no initial size so its not visible. I assume you want a fixed width and a variable height so I think this is what you want

```
JTextArea users = new JTextArea();
users.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, users.getHeight()));
add(users, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Comment: It works. I tried the same thing but with setMinimumSize() and forgot to check setPreferredSize(). Do you know why the first method does not work?

Comment: Not exactly. AFAIK `setMinimumSize()` and `setMaximumSize()` provides limits when scaling a component while frame is resized. `setPreferredSize()` defines an initial scaling. But not always sure when to use which.

Comment: He doesn't have to set a size, he could just call `jFrame.pack()`.

Comment: @SaclyrBarlonium No. The `JTextArea` has no initial size if it has no inital content. Also a `pack()` call will give zero width size.

Comment: @ArcticLord -  pack() uses the preferenced size. It's all automatic. Try to create a GUI without defining sizes. Something simple with BorderLayou. And in the end use it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with

```
frame.getContentPane().add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollChatPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.getContentPane().add(myMessage, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.getContentPane().add(users, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

You don't need setLayout if you use directly the JFrame's content pane

Answer (score 0):

You need to set component into your scroll pane.
For example if you need to scroll `myMessage`:

```
scrollChatPane.setViewportView(myMessage);
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(scrollChatPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(users, BorderLayout.EAST); // probably add(new JScrollPane(users), BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the JTextArea has a message to display. There are 3 different sizes to take into consideration when working with Swing classes: minimum size, maximum size and preferred size. Layouts will make use of these sizes in order to display components. In the case of BorderLayout, this should call getMinimumSize() on SOUTH, NORTH, WEST and EAST components, and getPreferredSize() for the CENTER component. A JTextArea's minimum size is the size required to fit the text, so a JTextArea with no text set will return a new Dimension(0, 0).

PS: Changes to Swing components performed at runtime should be done on the Swing threads via SwingUtilities. So if you define the text for the JTextArea at runtime you need to do the following

```
Runnable something = new Runnable(() -> {
    component.revalidate();
    component.repaint();
};
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(something);
```